# PHP: removing query parameters from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I returning the actual URL of my scripts with this PHP code:

```
// Returns actual URL with HTTP/HTTPS checking
$URL = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $URL ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Which is resulting:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/src/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

However if I use `urlencode` tags in my URL the result is this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8001/src/?keyword=all&page=0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

How I can remove this and not include `urlencode` in some of these source files?

Edit:

This is working, but I try to stay away such hardcoded solution:

```
$URL = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "127.0.0.1:{$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']}/src"
```

Comment: Are you confusing "urlencode" with the term *query parameters*?!

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer, so probably I confusing everything with every other possible things.

Comment: Then please try to clarify what you mean without necessarily using misleading technical jargon.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
// Returns actual URL with HTTP/HTTPS checking
$URL = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"
$URL =  parse_url($URL, PHP_URL_PATH);
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $URL ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The files in the `src` subfolder on the server, maybe because this?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP_SELF instead of REQUEST_URI

```
// Returns actual URL with HTTP/HTTPS checking
$URL = 'http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The files in the `src` subfolder on the server, maybe because this?

Comment: Sorry, just the `"` missed et the end. It also unclides index.php in the url field.

Comment: No unfortunately, index.php is part of the url.